# matplotlib function won't work with negative floats

Tags: python, matplotlib, valueerror

I am working in plotting a simple map with matplotlib which includes data from recent earthquakes. I am sizing the dots in the map according to each instance's magnitude, and it seems that there are some earthquakes that have negative magnitude.
When I run my code, I get this error:

The 'size' property is a number and may be specified as:
- An int or float in the interval [0, inf]
- A tuple, list, or one-dimensional numpy array of the above

It's pretty clear that this function will only accept positive numbers, however I cannot work out how to skip these values or work with a suitable function.
Here is my code:

```
import json
from plotly.graph_objs import Scattergeo, Layout
from plotly import offline
from plotly import colors

# explore the structure of the data
filename = "data/all_month.geojson"
with open(filename) as f:
    all_eq_data = json.load(f)
    
all_eq_dicts = all_eq_data["features"]
title = all_eq_data["metadata"]["title"]

mags, lons, lats, hover_texts = [], [], [], [],
for eq_dict in all_eq_dicts:
    if mag > 0:
        mags.append(eq_dict["properties"]["mag"])
        lons.append(eq_dict["geometry"]["coordinates"] [1])
        lats.append(eq_dict["geometry"]["coordinates"] [0])
        hover_texts.append(eq_dict["properties"]["title"])


# Map the earthquakes
data = [{
    "type": "scattergeo",
    "lon": lons,
    "lat": lats,
    "text": hover_texts,
    "marker": {
        "size": [5*mag for mag in mags],
        "color": mags,
        "colorscale": "Viridis",
        "reversescale": True,
        "colorbar": {"title": "Magnitude"},
    },
}]

my_layout = Layout(title=title)

fig = {"data": data, "layout": my_layout}
offline.plot(fig, filename="global_month_earthquakes_2023.html")
```

The condition if mag > 0 did not work either, I am still getting the same error. How can I solve this? Thank you!

Comment: Have you tried `"size": [5*mag if mag > 0 else 0 for mag in mags]`?

Comment: @teapot418 Are you sure? Should a magnitude -5 earthquake should be the same size on the plot as a magnitude 5 one?

Comment: @BRemmelzwaal you're right, that seems like a bad idea

Comment: `[max(0,5*mag) for mag in mags]` then

Comment: That's much better than my approach.